# How to replace a string with RegExp in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, regexp-replace

I want to replace a string with a variable.
For example my string is **'Hello {{world}}'** and I want to replace **{{world}}** with another text. The string to be replaced is always between curly brackets **{{}}**. After replacing with 'newtext' I expect the following result 'Hello newtext' (without curly brackets). How can I do this with RegExp in typescript?

Comment: Hello did you try formatted string ? Like ` `Hello ${value}` `

Comment: The same way you do it JavaScript, which is what TypeScript is transpiled into.

Comment: I assume that somewhere you have a dictionary containing `{"world": "newText"}` - so it’d be possible to build the string `{{world}}` from the keys of the dictionary and do a string replace without regexp.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to replace the whole expression with the brackets, you can do the following:

```js
const string = "Hello {{world}}";

console.log(string.replace(/{{.*}}/, "Stack overflow"));
```

Comment: This answer should be added to the original question rather than this duplicate.